# Same <T> - multiple times in a List<T> with different related entities- EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We have the following classes:

```
public class Article{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public double price {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Barcode> barcodes {get; set;}

}

public class Barcode {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public long Value{get; set;}
   public int ArticleId {get; set;}
   public Article Article {get; set;}
}
```

And, from a .csv file, I can get the same article ID in two different lines like this :

Line 1:  1234 | 591111111111111 | 13.49

Line 2:  1234 | 591111111111112 | 13.49

So, basically, two EAN barcodes can get you to the same Article.

Now, the import file contains well over 100.000 lines, that means, I will have the following code to import, after parsing the .csv :

```
 var List<Article> importedArticles = _csvParseFile(filePath):

 // how should i foreach this, so that, in the end, i would get one single batch insert (addRange), into the DB ?
```

Question in the code above.
I have some solutions in mind, but those are implying some O(n*m), which I would like to avoid at all costs.

The thing is, I would basically need to insert an article ID, the first time i see it in the list, and add the corresponding Barcode in the barcode table.
But, what happens if in the next line, I would find the same article ID, but with another EAN ? How can I treat this case ?

Comment: The Article table shouldn't have a foreign key to Barcode, so, you just need to insert the new Barcode when the Article has already been encountered. Keep a set of Article Ids while you parse to avoid  having to check the data.

Comment: Well, to start with, your csv format contains a lot of duplicates - not only the article Id, but also the Price. The first can be solved by populating `Dictionary<int, Arcticle>` instead of `List<Article>` in parse function, which is  O(n). Then you would use `db.Set<Article>().AddRange(dic.Values)`. How you will deal with price is something you need to figure out.

Comment: Price will always be the same, no matter the barcode, because it is linked to the itemId, not the barcode.

Comment: @AlexIvan That's obvious from the entity model. What I meant was that the csv format allows you to have two identical Ids with different Prices. e.g. in your example, Line 2: `1234 | 591111111111112 | 12.34`. Other than that, you know how to build dictionary, don't you? Create and add `Article` object if dictionary does not contain the id, otherwise use the existing. In both cases, create and add new `Barcode` object to the resolved `article.barcodes`.